# PHP: How to trim off everything before certain keywords in strings?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strstr, php-5.4

I have these type of results from a loop function,

```
C:/wamp/www/xxx/core/page/
C:/wamp/www/xxx/local/page/
```

But how can I trim off anything before **core** or **local**, so I get these only,

```
core/page/
local/page/
```

I use `strstr`, but I think it search for a fixed keyword only, I have two, many more keywords to match,

```
$string = 'C:/wamp/www/xxx/local/page/';
$output = strstr($string, '(local|core)');
var_dump($output);
```

I tried with `preg_replace`,

```
var_dump(preg_replace('#/(core|local)/.*#si', '/', $string));
```

it gives me the front part - `C:/wamp/www/xxx/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
$output = preg_replace('~^.*?((?:core|local).*$)~i', "$1", $string);
```

or

```
$output = preg_replace('~^.*?(?=core|local)~i', '', $string);
```

If you want to match strictly up to the folder `core` or `local`, you can use this:

```
$output = preg_replace('~^.*?/(?=(?:core|local)/)~i', '', $string);
```

[Viper-7 demo](http://viper-7.com/ocDAs1)

---

To your question:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('#/(core|local)/.*#si', '/', $string));
```

This will match `/(core|local)/.*` and replace it by `/`, which is not really what you're looking for, because you actually have to match what is before this. My first regex here is an example of that: it will match everything before `(?:core|local)` and then capture everything which comes afterwards into a capture group, which I'm referring to when using the backreference `$1`.

And well, because of the votewar going here... I added the forward slashes in the match, and you will be using less memory if you don't use a capture group at all (but using a lookahead), hence how I came to the last regex.

Comment: That looks better with backreferences, thank you, I forget about them

Comment: That's not overcomplicated. It's actually the simplest way(s) with `preg_replace`, avoiding too many captures.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be like:

```
$sData   = 'C:/wamp/www/xxx/local/page/';
$sResult = preg_replace('/^(.*?)\/(core|local)\/(.*?)$/', '$2/$3', $sData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)()**

```
<?
    $dir = "C:/wamp/www/xxx/core/page/";
    preg_match("#^.*?/((?:local|core).*/)$#i",$dir,$match);
    echo $match[1];
?>
```

If the first bit of the string is always the same you can use
`echo ltrim($dir, "C:/wamp/www/xxx/");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = substr($string, strpos($string,'local/')+strpos($string,'core/'));
```

Comment: Actually, not - since will do the stuff with `C:/wamp/www/xxx/score/page/`

Comment: omg
`$output = substr($string, strpos($string,'/local/')+strpos($string,'/core/')+strpos($string,'/score/')+1);`

Comment: This will fail if `$string = 'C:/wamplocal/www/xxx/local/page/';`. You should find position of `/local/` and not only `local/`.

Comment: @Jerry damn :p I knew I've missed something, but this is so stupid from my side :p Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different way using str_replace. Check below.

```
$string = 'C:/wamp/www/xxx/local/page/';
$output = str_replace('C:/wamp/www/xxx/' , '' , $string);
var_dump($output);
```

It will simply trim off the left side string.

Comment: I'm sure the `www` and `xxx` are meant to be example strings and could be _any_ character... so `str_replace` won't work here.

Answer (score -5):

```
preg_replace('/.*(core|local)/', "$1", $string);
```

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. Add the `/` if you think it's necessary, but don't waste my time with trivialites.

Comment: That regex will fail with `C:/wamp/www/xxx/local/page/local/file` as well. Not common, but not impossible either.